# Cookies not being set in the browser/postman

Tags: node.js, express, cors, session-cookies

I am running a nodejs server at and a nextjs server. They are hosted on render.com on following domains.
backend -> api.exampleexample.com
frontend -> domain.com

The problem is, I see that not cookies is being set on browser or on insomnia. This works perfectly fine when the run the servers in my local machine.

This is my cors and session configs

```
export async function initApp(app: any) {
    const cookie: CookieOptions = {};
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        console.log("cookie is being set for production");
        app.set("trust-proxy", true);
        cookie.secure = true;
        cookie.maxAge = 604800000;
        cookie.httpOnly = true;
        cookie.sameSite = "none";
        cookie.domain = cookieDomain;
    } else {
        cookie.secure = false;
        cookie.maxAge = 604800000;
        cookie.httpOnly = false;
    }

    app.use(
        session({
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            store: new TypeormStore({
                cleanupLimit: 2,
                ttl: 86400,
            }).connect(sessionRepository),
            secret: cookieSecret,
            cookie,
        })
    );

    const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
        origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? allowedOrigins : true,
        credentials: true,
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
        allowedHeaders: [
            "Content-Type",
            "Origin",
            "Authorization",
            "Set-Cookie",
            "Credentials",
            "Headers",
        ],
    };

    const controllerArray = Object.values(controllers);
    await useExpressServer(app, {
        middlewares: [RequestLogger, HttpErrorHandler, ResponseLogger],
        routePrefix: "/api",
        controllers: controllerArray,
        defaultErrorHandler: false,
        cors: corsOptions,
    });
}
```

cookieDomain is set to domain.com
allowed origins are https://www.example.com, https://example.com

I use axios to fetch from frontend and have an axios instance set up like this and use this to send requests.

```
axiosInstance: () => {
        return axios.create({
            baseURL: baseUrl,
            withCredentials: true
        })
    }
```

I use routing controllers and typeorm in my stack as well.

Have been trying to resolve this for 3 days now and have no idea what the issue here is. Would be awesome if someone can help me debug this.

Thanks

I have tried adjusting domain in set cookie header, but no use. I have also tried playing around with the configurations to no avail,

Comment: Hey, you can try **helmet** and **cookie-parser**. Helmet allows the app to use cookieparser. I faced the issue that the cookie was not created and after adding the helmet (`app.use(helmet())`) my issue was resolved. Hope it helps.

Comment: @myrn Express session should be ideally doing this for me. Anyway, we were able to set cookies with built in express res.cookie() function. Problem sorted for now.